# Celery chunks large data set

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to use celery's chunks functionality to divide my iterable dataset into pieces, which is then sent to a celery task for further processing.
I have a query_set that I got from making the following sqlalchemy call

```
query_set = MyModel.query.join(OtherModel).all())
```

Currently, query_set is a list of tuples. The lenth of query_results is at 40,000 and growing.

I have another function (celery task) that crunches the data in query_set, whose definition is

```
@celery_app.task
def crunch_qs(query_set):
    . . . 
    . . .
```

Since query_set is a list of tuples, I figured I could pass it directly to `crunch_qs` like this

```
crunched_qs = crunch_qs.chunks(query_set, 5000)()
results = crunched_qs.get()
```

That did not work. It gave me an unexpected result. It was unpacking the items in each query_set's tuple and sending them to `crunch_qs`.
So `crunch_qs` would receive **query_set[0] on first iteration, which raised the following error

TypeError: crunch_qs() takes exactly 1 argument (10 given)

len(query_set[0]) = 10

I also tried..

```
crunched_qs = crunch_qs.chunks((row,) for row in query_set, 5000)()
results = crunched_qs.get()
```

That worked a little better. The TypeError went away. However, my `crunch_qs` function is now getting each row (tuple) as a parameter instead of a list of tuples whose length is 5000.

Any help/ideas on how to pass a list of tuples to celery chunks would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance